# How to trigger a pageturn transition automatically without the gesture?

Tags: ios, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using an UIPageViewController with a PageControl to display  images in my PageViewController. All works perfect. But is it possible that the Pages are swiping (scrolling) to the next page after a specific time automatically?

Y have this code but dont work, i need UIPageViewController scroll automatically.

```
NSTimer *aTimer;
NSArray *viewControllers;


-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(animacion) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}


-(void)animation{

[pageVCObj setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:nil];
} 



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.


    self.pageController.doubleSided =YES;

    self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    self.pageController.dataSource = self;
    [[self.pageController view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];

    APPChildViewController5 *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

     viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];

    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
    [[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
    [self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer must not be running in the main loop. Try this:

```
aTimer = [[NSRunLoop mainLoop] addTimer:[NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(animacion) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in:

```
aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(animacion) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

You provide selector name `animacion` but your method is called `animation`.